# Executing java file using Process p=runtime.getRuntime().exec("java classname <input_file");

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to run the following program

```
import java.io.*;
class classname
{  public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(reader);
int t=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
System.out.println(t);
} }
```

I have created a seperate file input_file in which i have the input as 89

But when i try to execute the following code through

```
Process p=runtime.getRuntime().exec("java classname <input_file" );
```

It does not executes

I am trying to know that how can execute these file redirection commands using java Runtime or ProcessBuilder.

I am trying to create a web interface 
The web interface is something like online compiler e.g. ideone.com

The user will have its input in the input textarea and code in the code are

When user will click on compile it will show the output

But i cant the redirect the output of my input file for java classname

Comment: It does not execute...... => does it show an exception?? Is there anything you can tell what does happen?

Comment: I ran the following command through jsp 
 Process p=runtime.getRuntime().exec(“java classname <input_file”);

when i executed that the page keeps on loading only

Comment: With jsp do you mean JavaServer pages??

Comment: yes  java server pages

Comment: If the process variable is null then most probably an exception is thrown

since exec throws one of these 4:

SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its checkExec method doesn't allow creation of the subprocess
IOException - If an I/O error occurs
NullPointerException - If command is null
IllegalArgumentException - If command is empty

if it is not NULL then try to retrieve the ExitValue from the process and see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

The `java` command doesn't implement redirection. For that you need to run an enclosing command shell, for example `sh -c` or `cmd /c`.

Comment: can u be more clear with some code ?